# Gnuplot: Load command

Tags: load, gnuplot

I tried to separate the gnuplot environment commands and the data plot command. The gnuplot script is:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color
set output "/out.eps"
set size 0.80,0.80
...
...
load 'path/to/plot_command.txt
```

where `plot_command.txt` has the following commands:

```
plot '< tail -7 /Data2.stat' using 1:2 title "Data2" with lp lw 4, \
  '< tail -7 /Data3.stat' using 1:2 title "alnmindrepl07" with lp lw 4, \
   ....................................
```

However, I get the following error:

> plot '< tail -7 /Data2.stat' using 1:2 title "Data2" with lp lw 4,
>   ^
>   "/plot_command.txt", line 2: function to plot expected

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should be 'load 'path/to/plot_command.txt' . Did you miss a tick mark?

Comment: No, I have the tic around the file path, just a typo

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a ", \"  at the end of the second line of plot_command.txt.  The comma indicates that there will be another (third) function, hence the error. 
Try this instead:

```
plot '< tail -7 /Data2.stat' using 1:2 title "Data2" with lp lw 4, \
    '< tail -7 /Data3.stat' using 1:2 title "alnmindrepl07" with lp lw 4
```

Comment: Yes, I have that. This was just an example. My problem is that gnuplot is reporting the aforementioned error

Comment: ? - Read my answer again.  You should NOT have a comma at the end of the plot command.  Your error "/plot_command.txt", line 2: function to plot expected" occurs because the comma causes gnuplot to expect another function.

Comment: I don't have a ", \" at the end of the file. In my post, I showed the first few lines of the data file. The actual file does terminate without the ",". Thanks

Comment: can you show the whole file?  I think your problem is probably a syntax error in plot_command.txt.

Comment: Do you have a space after the backslash at the end of the line?  That would cause the backslash to escape the space instead of the carriage return effectively ending the command after one line.  Then gnuplot wouldn't find a second function after the comma in the plot command.